# spring MVC org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

This is the output I get in my Browser for a Spring MVC using REST

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:226)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:224)
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

It is fetching the list from database and also printing in console but for some reason it is unable to convert to JSON

here's my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

    <display-name>Restaurant</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet- 
    class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

here's my dispatcher servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.mvcrest.controller"></context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

I've searched around and most solutions point towards adding jackson dependencies in pom.xml but I already have them

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MvcRest</groupId>
    <artifactId>MvcRest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.47</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My controller is also being hit(I know this because the List is being printed in console)

```
@Controller
public class App {
    IRestaurantService res;

    public App() {
        try {
            res = new RestaurantService();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/menu", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Menu>> getmenu() {
        List<Menu> menus = res.getMenu();
        for (Menu menu : menus) {
            System.out.println(menu.getName());
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Menu>>(menus, HttpStatus.OK);
    }   
}
```

Here's my console log(I use Eclipse Photon for the record).

```
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MvcRest' did not find a matching property.
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.10
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 20 2018 17:32:21 UTC
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         9.0.10.0
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_102-b14
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\WorkSpace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\Tools\apache-tomcat-9.0.10
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\WorkSpace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\Tools\apache-tomcat-9.0.10
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\WorkSpace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\Tools\apache-tomcat-9.0.10\endorsed
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Maven\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files\Tomcat\bin\;C:\Users\M1048950\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\M1048950\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\windows\system32;;.]
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8030"]
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8090"]
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1426 ms
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.10
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:44 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:57 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:57 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:57 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Nov 12 17:47:57 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 12, 2018 5:47:58 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Nov 12, 2018 5:48:00 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry register
INFO: Mapped "{[/menu],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.mvcrest.entity.Menu>> com.mvcrest.controller.App.getmenu()
Nov 12, 2018 5:48:01 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Nov 12 17:47:57 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 12, 2018 5:48:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 4536 ms
Nov 12, 2018 5:48:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8030"]
Nov 12, 2018 5:48:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8090"]
Nov 12, 2018 5:48:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 27251 ms
Nov 12, 2018 5:48:03 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/MvcRest/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'


Burger
Pizza
Pasta
Nutella
Steak
Ice Cream    

Nov 12, 2018 5:48:08 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpMessageNotWritable
    WARNING: Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList
```

I am hitting the endpoint "http://localhost:8030/MvcRest/menu" using Browser(Tried Postman too but that shouldn't make a difference and is irrelavent here).

Been at it for 3 Days. Any help is Much Appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your dispatcher servlet config xml file make sure you have this:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
     <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
   </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

The above code adds the necessary convertors.

Don't forget to add the namespace for **mvc**.

Comment: Thank you very much, It did it. But can you explain in a little detail or point me to a source as to why these converters are necessary because my friend has the exact same code and it works in his system without these converters.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `@RequestMapping` to `@GetMapping` or or change it from `ResponseEntity<>` to `@ResponseBody`

**Example 1**

```
@GetMapping("/menu")
public ResponseEntity<List<Menu>> getmenu() {
    List<Menu> menus = res.getMenu();
    for (Menu menu : menus) {
        System.out.println(menu.getName());
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Menu>>(menus, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Example 2**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/menu", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Menu> getmenu() {
    List<Menu> menus = res.getMenu();
    for (Menu menu : menus) {
        System.out.println(menu.getName());
    }
    return menues;
}
```

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity

One last thing; youre `IRestaurantService` should be annotated as a `@Service` in the class or what implements it and then should be autowired into your controller so you do not have to instantiate it.

```
@Service
public class RestarauntService implements IRestaurantService {
  ...
}
```

Then

```
@Controller
public class App {
    @Autowired
    private RestaurantService res; 

    ....

}
```

Comment: I had tried **@GetMapping** beforehand and also **@ResponseBody** didn't work either.
Also i wanted to try this project without @Autowired. Thank you anyways.